# Android ImageView From URL: Not Getting Set (Using Picasso)

Tags: android, picasso

I'm brand new to Android development, so I'm probably doing something stupid. Any ideas why this code shouldn't work?

It compiles and runs, but doesn't actually successfully set the image (which is previously set to a gray background).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);
    Button getImageButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.btnGetImage));
    getImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) (findViewById(R.id.myImageView));
            Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load("https://www.example.com/someimage").into(myImageView);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try with Activity Context instead Button View Context

Comment: Lazy to post an answer these days nobody accepts them :P
Picasso is a library and not an application. While creating Picasso instance if you'll not pass `context`, then how do you think it will get the application context from ? For it to work it requires `context` , and it definitely needs to be provided by the `application` using this library.It also prevents leaking an Activity (if that's what you pass ,some of below answers have used ) by switching to the application context. use `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Colin are you sure about your url ? does that point to an image

Comment: @Colin check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> alter you code this way

```
Picasso.with(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this).load("https://www.example.com/someimage").into(myImageView);
```

Here `v.getContext()` is not related to the main context, so it won't help you, we need to pass context of current activity

Comment: just asking so to what `v.getContext()` is realted to?

Comment: In general there are two type of classes. Ones that extend ContextWrapper class (Activity, Service, Application) and those that do not extend it (like View).

If class extends ContextWrapper then you can use this as Context. Such classes normally do not have getContext() method.
Those classes that do not extend ContextWrapper but still save and use Context normally expose getContext() function. And you cannot use this as Context in such cases.
And these two cases are mutually exclusive. At least I don't recall classes that extend ContextWrapper and have getContext at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up: when I use "MyActivityName.this", what exactly is happening? It's apparently different than just "this".

Comment: @Colin If you use "this", you can see Picasso code is written inside new OnClickListner(), so "this" points to current object of that Class, and we need context of current activity, so we need to add context of our current activity

Comment: @Mrinmoy - to further clarify my question, I understand what "this" is in general (I have a mostly C# background, so "this" is old hat), but it appears to be different than "MyActivityName.this". Can you be more specific about how "MyActivityName.this" differs?

Comment: @Colin try printing "this" and "ActivityName,this" inside onClick()  your question will be answered. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and let me know.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);
        Button getImageButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.btnGetImage));
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) (findViewById(R.id.myImageView));
        getImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Picasso.with(YourActivityName.this).load("https://www.example.com/someimage").into(myImageView);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ding ding here is my answer

I am sure that you add the dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and used the right url

`Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

---

I am telling you where you went wrong !!

Magic : Have you added the internet permission ? It needs to be in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Rather than that your code is just fine

But i recommend you to use `getApplicationContext()`

copying from my comment

> `Picasso` is a library and not an application. While creating
>   `Picasso` instance if you'll not pass context, then how do you think
>   it will get the application context from ? For it to work it requires
>   context , and it definitely needs to be provided by the application
>   using this library.It also prevents leaking an Activity (if that's
>   what you pass ,some of below answers have used ) by switching to the
>   application context. use `getApplicationContext()`

And for the people who randomly put an answer here read this as well

- `View.getContext()`:  Returns the context the view is currently running in.  Usually the currently active Activity.
- `Activity.getApplicationContext()`:  Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside
  of).  Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a
  context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the
  current Activity.
- `ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()`:  If you need access to a Context from within another context, you use a ContextWrapper.  The
  Context referred to from inside that ContextWrapper is accessed via
  `getBaseContext()`.

so any way he is accessing the currant activity context.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**step 1 In Menifest check Internet Connection**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**step 2** `compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"`

**step 3 Image url is not showing any image in browser paste your url in browser and if you get image then you can set that image to imagview**

**step 4 check url is working or not there is not .png or .jpg extension for imagfile**

@Override

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);

            Button getImageButton = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.btnGetImage));

            getImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   
   //Initializing the ImageView
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Loading Image from URL
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("https://www.example.com/someimage")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   // optional
            .error(R.drawable.error)      // optional
            .resize(400,400)                        // optional
            .into(imageView);
}
});
}
```

Comment: Read the question first> (Using Picasso)

Comment: i have change code but if imag url is not working then its not working . so image url should be right